# How can I retrieve the table structure from a sql database?

Tags: sql, database, table-structure

So basically I want a SQL Command that return every column in the table and the datatype that is in that column and whether is nullable.

Comment: *Which* implementation of SQL? Also, did you search at all before asking? I feel like this must have been asked already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use information schema.

```
SELECT 
  COLUMN_NAME,
  DATA_TYPE, 
  IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
```

Comment: I had to add an " USE 'DatabaseName'" but now it works.